# Basic question on local compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Let $A \subset F \subset X$.

Let $F$ be a subspace of $X$.

Let $A$ be a subspace of $F$.

Suppose that under this subspace topology inherited from $F$, $A$ forms a locally compact topological space.

Now let $A$ is a subspace of $X$.

Then how can I show that under the subspace topology inherited from $X$, $A$ is a locally compact topological space?

Comment: The relative topology on $A$ inherited by the relative topology on $F$ is the same as the relative topology on $A$ inherited from $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the topology that $A$ inherits from $F$ is *the same topology* that it inherits from $X$ (since the topology of $F$ is the one that it inherits from $X$). That's so because, for both topologies, a subset $O$ of $A$ is open if and only if $O=O^\star\cap A$, for some open subset $O^\star$ of $X$.